# ngResource is not working in my project, imported cdn for angularjs version 1.3.14, angular-resource 1.3.14

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

Injected 'ngResouce',
Created factory and used $resource in that.
Passed factory name to Controller.

Its giving error

"Error: [$injector:unpr] "

Comment: Can you create a Plunkr to show us ?

Comment: Are you sure you are including the `angular-resource.min.js` in your index?

Comment: Yeah, Edward, i have included angular-resource.js

Comment: Did you included "ngResource" in your `angular.module('myApp', [... , ngResource, ....]` declaration?

Answer (score 1):

can you provide more details around your query, i see you have mentioned $resource.

**$resource** is a factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources.

from your question its not clear how you are injecting the resource, if you are defining a module you may try this

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);
```

and for creating a **factory** you may try the below code,

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource']) 
.factory('myfactory', function($resource){ 
// your code here 
});
```